# Bucket Data Names in PySpark with Meaningful Bucket Names

Tags: python, pyspark, binning

I have a function in PySpark to bucket (or bin) data using the `Bucketizer`. Since `Bucketizer` returns numeric values for the buckets, I also have another function called `create_bin_col_names()` used in the main function create bucket names that makes sense.

This is what my functions look like,

```
def binning_data(df: DataFrame, bin_data_list: list) -> DataFrame:
    """ This method creates bins for numerical values based on the column and the bins
    defined in the parameter.yml file.

    Args:
        :param df: Data frame which has the columns to be binned.
        :param bin_data_list: A list which defined columns and bin ranges.
    Returns:
        :rtype: df: Output data frame
    """

    for col_data in bin_data_list:
        column_name = col_data.upper()

        bin_list = bin_data_list[col_data]
        bin_list.insert(0, -float("inf"))
        bin_list.append(float("inf"))
        splits = bin_list

        df = df.withColumn(column_name, df[column_name].cast(DoubleType()))

        bucketizer = Bucketizer(
            splits=splits, inputCol=column_name, outputCol=column_name + "_bin123"
        )
        df = bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("keep").transform(df)

        d = create_bin_col_names(bin_data_list[col_data])

        mapping_expr = f.create_map([f.lit(x) for x in chain(*d.items())])
        df = df.withColumn(
            column_name, mapping_expr[f.col(column_name + "_bin123")]
        ).drop(f.col(column_name + "_bin123"))

    return df

def create_bin_col_names(bin_list: list) -> dict:
    """ This function creates names for bins.

        Args:
            :param bin_list: A list which contains bins
        Returns:
            :rtype: dict: Output data dictionary with bin names
    """

    d = {}
    x = 0
    for item in bin_list:
        x += 1
        if x == 1:
            d.update({x - 1: "<" + str(item).strip()})
        else:
            d.update({x - 1: str(prev_name).strip() + "-" + str(item).strip()})
        prev_name = item
    d.update({x: ">" + str(item).strip()})

    return d
```

This works without a problem, but the bucket names assigned do not seem to be accurate. It always seems to be a bucket class less than the one that should ideally be assigned.

What am I doing wrong here? If there is another, less complicated approach I am open to trying that as well.